# handling templates and widgets for custom content types

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I have created a custom content type (and taxonomy) for my theme that will mostly replace the default post type. I know as for singles, i can create a template single-customtype.php to handle this but what about for everything else?

what about http://mywebsite.com/posttype (is my only option forcing my theme user to create a page and select a template?)

what about search, 404, archive and widgets? Would i have to customize them all. I can tell i am missing something huge here but i cant put my finger on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for search you might need to adjust query to include your custom post type, `search.php` template or around that;
- 404 page is completely unrelated to post types;
- for archive you use `archive-customtype.php` template;
- sidebars/widgets are completely unrelated to post types.

Comment: how can i replicate "home" behavior for my custom type (or is my only option forcing theme user to create a page and to choose a template?)

Comment: @Jeele Yah see [Showing custom post types on your home/blog page](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/02/02/showing-custom-post-types-on-your-home-blog-page)

Comment: Thanks! I believe i have finally found that BUMP in the wordpress learning curve